# Proving simple shuffling algorithm does work.

Tags: algorithms

I don't know if this is the correct site to ask, but I do think it is, as proving the correctness of an algorithm is something I think belongs to mathematics.

I wrote this simple **$c$** code below, which is supposed to take an array and shuffle the elements in it and I want to prove conclusively that it does work.

I made some tests and it seems to be correct, but that obviously proves nothing.

How could I attemp to prove this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int shuffle(int v[], int dim);

int
main(void)
{
    int vector[10]={1,23,56,3,2};
    int i, dimen=5;
    shuffle(vector,dimen);
    for(i=0;i<dimen;i++)
        printf("vector[%d]=%d\n",i, vector[i]);
    return 0;
}

int
shuffle(int v[], int dim){
    int saveValue, randIndex, i;
    srand(time(0));
    randIndex=rand()%dim;
    saveValue=v[randIndex];
    for(i=0;i<dim; i++, randIndex=rand()%dim)
    {
        saveValue=v[i];
        v[i]=v[randIndex];
        v[randIndex]=saveValue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "work" mean here?

Comment: That the resulting array will have the same set of elements and they will be permuted (the identity permutation is allowed).

Comment: You can prove that the array contains the same set of elements in the end by proving that set of elements in the array is a *loop invariant*, i.e. that each iteration of the loop doesn't change the set. Slightly more difficult to prove, but also true, is that the resulting permutation is uniformly randomly sampled from all permutations of the array.

Comment: Three comments on the code: a) The dimension of `vector` should be $5$, not $10$? b) The first assignment to `saveValue` has no effect. c) `randIndex=rand()%dim` would be better placed at the beginning of the loop instead of duplicating it before the loop and in the loop update.

Comment: Could you help me out with a sketch on those proofs? I've never done a proof regarding an algorithm (also thanks for correcting my code haha, I'm quite a newbie there).

Comment: @joriki: As programmed, the algorithm is very far from uniform, as Adriano's answer points out.

Comment: @TonyK: Thanks. Interesting. That was a real failure of intuition -- it should have been clear from the divisibility problem that it can't be uniform, but it feels so uniform because "every element gets shuffled".

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think that the distribution of this algorithm will be uniform. [You should probably use this one instead.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm)

To see this, suppose that the initial array is $[1, 2, 3]$. There are $3! = 6$ distinct possible permutations. However, your algorithm will uniformly produce one of the following $3^3 = 27$ (repeated) permutations (the left part lists the `randIndex` choices, and the right part lists the output array):
\begin{align*}
(0, 0, 0) &\implies [3, 1, 2] \\
(0, 0, 1) &\implies [2, 3, 1] \\
(0, 0, 2) &\implies [2, 1, 3] \\
(0, 1, 0) &\implies [3, 2, 1] \\
&~~~~~~\vdots \\
(2, 2, 2) &\implies [3, 1, 2]
\end{align*}
Since $27$ is not divisible by $6$, it's impossible for the $27$ results to be equally distributed amongst the $6$ possible buckets.

Comment: Hmm I think I understand what you mean, but if I only wanted to prove that the algorithm outputs some permutation of the original array, how would that go about? Also, is there a way to check which permutations will have more chance to be rolled?

Comment: The only operations that you perform to modify the array are swaps. Swaps preserve the elements in an array (nothing is created nor destroyed). So the output is some permutation of the original array.

Comment: Thanks, @Adriano. Regarding the algorithm not distributing uniformly the permutations, could you expand a bit on that? I could not understand what the table means.